# Change node location with xslt 1.0 to "sibling" node at same position without attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I change the location of node "//seps/ink[x]/c" to the same position in node "inks/ink[x]". I only found solutions using attributes.

Source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<root>
 <inks>
  <ink>
   <A>A1</A>
   <B>B1</B>
 </ink>
 <ink>
  <A>A2</A>
  <B>B2</B>
 </ink>
</inks>
<seps>
 <ink>
  <C>C1</C>
 </ink>
 <ink>
  <C>C2</C>
 </ink>
</seps>
</root>
```

Target:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<root>   
 <inks>
  <ink>
   <A>A1</A>
   <B>B1</B>
   <C>C1</C>
  </ink>
  <ink>
   <A>A2</A>
   <B>B2</B>
   <C>C2</C>
  </ink>
 </inks>
</root>
```

Thanks a lot for helpful solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="inks/ink">
     <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
     <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/seps/ink[$vPos]/C"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="seps"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
 <inks>
  <ink>
   <A>A1</A>
   <B>B1</B>
 </ink>
 <ink>
  <A>A2</A>
  <B>B2</B>
 </ink>
</inks>
<seps>
 <ink>
  <C>C1</C>
 </ink>
 <ink>
  <C>C2</C>
 </ink>
</seps>
</root>
```

**Produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<root>
   <inks>
      <ink>
         <A>A1</A>
         <B>B1</B>
         <C>C1</C>
      </ink>
      <ink>
         <A>A2</A>
         <B>B2</B>
         <C>C2</C>
      </ink>
   </inks>
</root>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The [***identity rule***](https://www.delightfulcomputing.com/xslfaq/xsl/sect2/identity.html) copies every node "as-is" if a higher priority template doesn't match this node.
2. Subtrees of elements of type `inks/ink` are processed by the code as in the identity rule, but extended with one final application of it to the corresponding `sep/ink/C` element. The current position of the matched `inks/ink`  (`current()`) element, stored in a variable, is used to select the wanted corresponding `seps/ink` element
3. Processing of the subtree with root the `seps` element is suppressed (effectively "deleting" it from the result of the transformation, by an empty matching template

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you process `root/inks/ink` with e.g. `xsl:apply-templates` (or with the identity transformation but `xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` in place), you can either store `<xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()"/>` and use that variable as an index in the other path e.g. `/root/seps/ink[$pos]/C` or in general, if you don't want to rely on processing those `ink` elements explicitly, in the template matching e.g. `<xsl:template match="root/inks/ink">`, you can always compute the position with `xsl:number` in a variable e.g. `<xsl:variable name="pos"><xsl:number/></xsl:variable>`. Then you can use that variable with e.g. `/root/seps/ink[position() = $pos]/C`.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 3.0, you could use `xsl:merge`, or the `fn:for-each-pair` function.

But 1.0 is more limited, and the only way to merge two sequences is along the lines

```
<xsl:variable name="root" select="."/>
<xsl:for-each select="inks/ink">
  <xsl:variable name="p" select="position()"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="$root/seps/ink[$p]"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```